# Constraining a database table so only one row can have a particular value in a column

Tags: sql, oracle11g, unique-index

I am brand new to SQL and I am trying to figure out an error message I get when I try to follow the suggestions in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182262/how-to-constrain-a-database-table-so-only-one-row-can-have-a-particular-value-in) to enforce only one 'Yes' in my column.

```
DROP TABLE team  CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
create table team (
  name varchar2(4) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  isTeamLead char(3) 
    check (isTeamLead in ('Yes')));

create unique index only_one_yes on team(isTeamLead)
(case when col='YES' then 'YES' end);
```

The error report is as follows:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02158: invalid CREATE INDEX option
02158. 00000 -  "invalid CREATE INDEX option"
*Cause:    An option other than COMPRESS, NOCOMPRESS, PCTFREE, INITRANS,
           MAXTRANS, STORAGE, TABLESPACE, PARALLEL, NOPARALLEL, RECOVERABLE,
           UNRECOVERABLE, LOGGING, NOLOGGING, LOCAL, or GLOBAL was specified.
*Action:   Choose one of the valid CREATE INDEX options.
```

Any thoughts?

**Running Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0**

Comment: What is col in the CASE statement? Oracle doesn't identify that and reports an error while creating index. `create unique index only_one_yes on team(isTeamLead);` will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `case` part of the `create index` statement. This executes OK:

```
create table team (
  name varchar2(4) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  isTeamLead char(3) check (isTeamLead in ('Yes'))
);

create unique index only_one_yes on team(isTeamLead);

insert into team values ('x', 'Yes');
insert into team values ('y', null);
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6b447).

Comment: Ok. If I include project column in the table and want to have one team lead per project, it looks like using index would not work. You can test the [code here](http://ideone.com/ApF2sU) on SQLFiddle. I am wondering if I can have only one `Yes` per project but as many `null` as possible. Thanks.

Comment: See if [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/528ca8) helps. You could add a trigger to the table to create unique "non 'Yes'" values using the row number or id column etc when the provided insert value is null.